# Ondrag function lagging in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a custom player with SoundCloud widget API.I have used onDragstart,onDrag and onDragEnd function for the seek bar update.But when I drag the icon is getting lag.Can you please help me how can make it smooth.